# Create subplots with plotly using a loop

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Is there a way to create a subplot with Plotly Express using a for to plot the data? I've tried some things here but nothing worked as expected. This is my last try:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=int(len(unique_pds)/2), cols=2)

for pds in unique_pds:
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Histogram(x=df[(df['Resolved'] >= resolved_date) &
        (df['Components'].astype(str).str.contains(components)) &
        (df['planned_effort'] == pds)]['lead_time']
                     )
    ).show()
```

The solution works almost perfectly, but the problem is that it is generating various subplots separated. I need all of them to be under the same subplot.

Thanks for the help.
Marcelo

Comment: What you mean is that you want to stack many histograms into one X&Y axis?

Comment: I think we should stop subplotting and just do this. `fig = go.Figure()`

Comment: Actually, I want to have 1 figure with for example 6 tiny plots on it.